# Is there a shorter alternative for 100's of fields?

Tags: c#, sql

I have lots of fields that I need to transfer to a SQL server database table which I'm getting a few problems with `NULL` values.

I can get around it using something similar to

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {

  SqlCommand cmd_insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AccStats (Field1 , Field2 ,
     Field3) VALUES (@value1 , @value2 , @value3)", conn);

  if (record.commRate == null)
  {
    cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", DBNull.Value);
  }
  else
  {
    cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", record.commRate);
  }

  //Lots more fields

  conn.Open();
  cmd_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn.Close();

}
```

I just wanted to know if there was a neater/shorter way of doing this rather than writing out this 100's of times for all the fields?

```
  if (record.commRate == null)
  {
        cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", DBNull.Value);
  }
  else
  {
        cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", record.commRate);
  }
```

Comment: Having hundreds of fields is certainly weird (read bad design). Do your fields have names, or are they numbered like in your example?

Comment: The 'hundreds of fields' are not all going into 1 table, thankfully. I've also changed the field names to something very mundane - they do have better descriptions in real life!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure; that is actually a perfect fit for [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper)

```
conn.Execute(
    "INSERT INTO AccStats (Field1,Field2,Field3) VALUES (@commRate,@anotherField,@yetAnotherField)", 
   record);
```

Basically, dapper treats the (single) parameter object as a key-value store - because `@commRate` is in the command, it adds `record.commRate`, using the using rules including `null` vs `DBNull` (and likewise for `record.anotherField` and `record.yetAnotherField`).

Comment: Of course - though I believe I would really need to get to know its internals well to be effective with dapper.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that will return `DBNull.Value` or the actual value:

```
private object DBNullOrValue<T>(T val) where T : class
{
   if(val == null)
     return DBNull.Value;

   return val;
}
```

Comment: Can't we simply do cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", record.commRate??DbNull.Value);

Comment: @Maheep - Sure. Many ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your favorite:

1)

```
cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", record.commRate ?? DBNull.Value);
```

2)

```
public static object NullToDBNull(this object val) 
{
   return val ?? DBNull.Value;
}

cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", record.commRate.NullToDBNull());
```

3)

```
public static void AddNullable(this SqlParameterCollection parameters, 
                            string paramName, object newParameter)
{
    parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, newParameter ?? DBNull.Value);
}

cmd_insert.Parameters.AddNullable("@value1", record.commRate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Sql server Bulk copy.

Example:

```cs
string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                // Create a table with some rows. 
                using (var newSessionResults = MakeTable(results))
                {
                    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tablename";

                        try
                        {
                            // Write from the source to the destination.
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newSessionResults);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```